# How to use between clause for getting data between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have date field in the database in the format **2012-03-17 19:50:08.023**.

I want to create a select query which gives me the data collected in the **March** month. 
But I am not able to achieve this.

I am trying following query.

```
select * from OrderHeader where
Convert(varchar,UploadDt,103) between '01/03/2013' and '31/03/2013' 
and DistUserUniqueID like  '6361%'
```

This query gives me data for all the dates.

```
select * from OrderHeader where
UploadDt between '01/03/2013' and '31/03/2013' and DistUserUniqueID like  '6361%'
```

This query gives me the error as *Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use  varchar (11). Specify length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first query returns all dates because you are converting your column to a string. Not sure why you are doing this. So when you say `BETWEEN '01/anything' AND '31/anything'`, when you consider it is now just a string, that is going to match all "dates" in the column, regardless of month and year, since your `WHERE` clause will cover every single day possible (well, with the exception of the 31st of months other than March, and the first day in January and February - so not all the data but a very large percentage). `'15/11/2026'`, for example, is `BETWEEN '01\03\2013' AND '31/03/2013'`.

Think about that for a second. You have datetime data in your database, and you want to convert it to a string before you query it. Would you also convert salary to a string before comparing it? If so, the person making $70,000 will look like they are making more than the person making $690,000, since character-based sorting starts at the first character and doesn't consider length.

The second query fails because you are using a regional, ambiguous format for your dates. You may like `dd/mm/yyyy` but clearly your server is based on US English formatting where `mm/dd/yyyy` is expected.

The solution is to use a proper, unambiguous format, such as `YYYYMMDD`.

```
BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130313'
```

However [you shouldn't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - since this is a `DATETIME` column you should be using:

```
WHERE UploadDt >= '20130301'
  AND UploadDt <  '20130401'
```

(Otherwise you will miss any data from `2013-03-31 00:00:00.001` through `2013-03-31 23:59:59.997`.)

If you really like `BETWEEN` then on 2008+ (you didn't tell us your version) you can use:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, UploadDt) BETWEEN '20130301' AND '20130331'
```

More date-related tips here:

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Finally, [when converting to `VARCHAR` (or any variable-length data types), always specify a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite the query as

```
select * from OrderHeader where
UploadDt between '01/03/2013' and '01/04/2013' 
and DistUserUniqueID like  '6361%'
```

or

```
select * from OrderHeader where
UploadDt between Convert(datetime,'01/03/2013', 103) and Convert(datetime,'01/04/2013',103) 
and DistUserUniqueID like  '6361%'
```

Comment: Both of these will return data from April 1st at midnight. This changes the meaning of the query. Also your first version only sidesteps the issue because neither day nor month exceeds 12. I suspect this will return data from January 3rd to January 4th, not the intention of the original query.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: the datetimeformat parameter with value 103 takes care of the sidestepping. This is working fine at my end and I have been using it. 103 is for 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Its better to be hands-on rather than downvoting on suspicion. :)

Comment: Thanks, I believe I understand how 103 takes care of the sidestepping. But you don't have 103 in your first query, right? See how I said "your first version"? There are still multiple other issues here that won't solve the OP's actual problem.